# Transaction do not shows up in my android wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have an incoming transaction that didn't show up in my android wallet
[here is the txid[[1](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/3461c401316cc5a053a6655004b6a82d1496bd1eca9d350e01fdf87f57f40963)

I tried to re-sync the wallet and the transaction is still missing!
I noticed you use blockexplorer.com as block explorer, is this a BITCOIN wallet or a B CASH one?

Please help me to recover my funds it's more than 0.05 btc

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the wallet and make sure that you use a bitcoin wallet since this is a Bitcoin transaction

If you have the private key of the destination wallet, then your funds should be okey

Comment: Problem solved thx